# Rails where clause with a logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table where I am storing age ranges.

The age range is saved as Range object e.g. `(1..4)` in ruby. Now when I have to fetch all the records where one age falls in the age range. I have to do this

```
table.select{|s| s.age_range.include?(19)}
```

but this returns an array , not an active record relation object. So I would prefer doing something like:

```
table.where(s.age_range:  age_range.include?(19)}
```

which is obviously not correct. But its gets the point across. I would like to know if this is possible .

**model.rb**

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :age_range_min, :age_range_max

  before_create :set_age_range
  serialize :age_range

  def set_age_range
    self.age_range = (age_range_min.to_i..age_range_max.to_i)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hm, mysql stores ranges? Last I checked, it didn't have a column type for this.

Comment: Okay I should clarify this a little more, its not storing ruby ranges, but yaml format text. I thought this was not required.

Comment: Show relevant section of your model too, then

Comment: @SergioTulentsev added model code to show how I am saving the age range

Comment: So, your range is only range when you fetch it into the app. In the database, it's an unqueryable text blob. What you want is not possible, given your current schema. If you store range start/end in different integer columns in database, then you can query it.

Comment: got it. So it is not possible with mysql because it is a text blob. But is it possible in rails ?

Comment: Rails does it, after fetching the data. At this point, it's an array and not an AR::Relation.

Comment: You'd be better with `min_age` and `max_age` columns, right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, because SQL doesn't understand or know how to interpret the text blob, it can't extract the required records.

But if you're not necessarily looking for a performant solution (i.e. you just want an ActiveRecord::Relation) then you can use the resulting array to do this...

```
ids = Model.select{|s| s.age_range.include?(19)}.map(%:id)
relation = Model.where(id: ids)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this was also considered and ruled out based on the double query problem

Comment: In that case best solution would be to add :age_range_min and :age_range_max to your model and remove the 'attr_accessor' .  This would work automatically for all new records, but your migration would need to handle existing records... maybe have a line like... Model.all{|m| m.age_range_min = m.age.range.to_a.first; m.age_range_max = m.age_range.to_a.last; m.save(validate:false)}